# How to install SharePoint Subscription Edition and Azure DevOps Server Express on Same Windows Server 2022

Tags: iis, azure-devops, sharepoint

Problem: Managed to install SharePoint Server on Windows server. After installing Azure DevOps Server, I cannot access my Azure DevOps default collection site but I can access my SharePoint site.

Managed to install SharePoint Subscription Edition on Windows Server 2022. Steps taken are:

Followed the steps illustrated in the youtube link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg1iQp8pvqk

1. Renamed computer
2. Installed Windows SQL with 2 separate instances. One for SharePoint and One for Azure DevOps Server express
3. Installed Active Domain Services
4. Installed SharePoint Subscription Edition
5. Binded SharePoint with Self Signed Certified and configure a HTTPS sharepoint site.

Installed Azure DevOps Server Express on the other MS SQL instance and configured public URL to bind to HTTPS.

I repeated the installation steps as described above on 2 separate windows server VM. One windows server 2022 VM for SharePoint server and one windows server 2022 vm for Azure DevOps server express. And they work perfectly. My initial assessment, Azure DevOps Server installation conflicts with existing IIS configuration from the SharePoint installation.

Please assist me to configure the Azure DevOps server express and SharePoint Server on the same windows server. I am trying to create my home lab to study SPFX and azure devops pipeline. Thank you.

Comment: You really shouldn't self-host Azure DevOps Server alongside other software.

Comment: If you are truly setting up a lab, start from a Hyper-V server and then put all different types of servers on guest VMs.

Comment: 1) I have installed hyper v on windows 11 Home edition but preferred the UI and convenience of proxmox. 2) I prefer to run SharePoint on premise, Azure DevOps express on a single VM. For convenience of maintenance of a single VM. Therefore, if technically possible, please guide me to install Azure DevOps on an existing windows server with SharePoint installed. I suspect the main cause is the conflicting iis configuration.

Comment: Oh Lex, I might have misinterpreted your suggestion. Are you suggesting that I should install hyper v on my windows server which is a proxmox VM. Followed by installing the SharePoint subscription edition as a hyper v VM. This is followed by installing Azure DevOps on another hyper v VM. By doing so, I can achieve one proxmox VM with SharePoint and Azure DevOps?

Comment: Can anyone guide me to install both SharePoint on Subscription Edition and Azure Devops Server Express on a single Windows server? I realised the suggestion by Lex is not what i want to achieve.